# increasing or decreasing qty if checkbox remain checked and add button is click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

what i want to do is , i have check-box in table rows, and a add/remove button, i want a situation where if the add button is click while a particular check-box remain checked the qty for that particular check-box increase or decrease when remove button is click. sorry i don't have an idea on how to do this, using j-query. please can any help be given thanks in advance

```
   $('.addbtn').on('click', function(){


            var len =$('input:checked').parent().siblings('td').length;
            var tablechild;
           var qty="";
                  $('input:checked').each(function(){

            $this = $(this);
        tablechild = "<tr>";
        tablechild +="<td>"+qty+"</td>";
                for(i=0; i<len; i++){
                    tablechild += "<td>";
                    tablechild += $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(i).text();
                    tablechild += "</td>";
                }   

        tablechild += "</tr>";
        $('.orderpanel tbody').append(tablechild);
        qty++;
        });
```

Comment: What do you expect `$().val()` to do ?

Comment: @adeneo just edited the code

Comment: no need for the .each, just do: $this = $('input:checked');  And I would suggest you put an id or class on that input, rather than using the global search for any checked inputs. <input type="checkbox" id="addcheck" /> $('#addcheck').is(':checked') (returns true or false)

Comment: @Lathan i want to be able to identify the checkbox that is ckecked if it is the same or another checkbox

Comment: Some example of what html structure you are dealing with could be helpful. Can you make a working example on jsfiddle.net ?